# JavaScript Dynamic Button OnClick Event Only Aplies To Last Button Created

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to dynamically add rows to a table and each row has a delete button.

When I click the delete button I want to get the ID of the row which contains that specific delete button.

The row IDs are correctly assigned in my code and appear right when I inspect the HTML.

But when I run my code the function only applies to the last button created and I only get the ID of the last row in my table regardless of which button I click.

So all of my buttons call the function but the onClick only gets the ID of the last row containing the last button created regardless of which button is clicked.

For example if there are 5 rows the ID I would get back would be 5 even if the button in the second row is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code (I left out the unimportant parts of it):

```
for (let x = 1; x < localStorage.length+1; x++) {

var row = table.insertRow(x);
     row.id = String(x);

var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
     deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
     deleteButton.type = "button";
     deleteButton.className = "deleteButton";

     deleteButton.onclick = function() {

       var rowID = deleteButton.closest("tr")?.id;      

     }

     cell4.append(deleteButton);

     table.append(row);

}
```

SOLUTION: Make my table a constant and change the "var"s to "let"s

JS Function:

```
function viewUsers()
   {

    const table = document.getElementById("outputTable");

    for(var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      table.deleteRow(i);
    }

    for (let x = 1; x < 5; x++) { 

     let row = table.insertRow(x);
     row.id = String(x);

     let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
     let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

     cell1.innerHTML = "Cell1";
     cell2.innerHTML = "Cell2";
     cell3.innerHTML = "Cell3";


     let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
     deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
     deleteButton.type = "button";
     deleteButton.id = "deleteButton"; 
     deleteButton.className = "deleteButton";

     deleteButton.onclick = function() {

      let rowID = deleteButton.closest("tr").id;
        alert(rowID);

     }

     cell4.append(deleteButton);

     table.append(row);

   }

  }
```

HTML

```
<table id="outputTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<button onclick ="viewUsers()">
 Load
</button>
```

Comment: Please add html code and some more JS code to make the question more understandable. It would be even better if you can give a stackblitz link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that `var` is not scoped to the for loop so when you create deleteButton the `deleteButton` variable is only created once, gets assigned to in each iteration of the loop and that one variable is what gets used by the onclick function. If you use `let`, each iteration of the loop will have its own `deleteButton` variable.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table');

for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  let row = table.insertRow(x);
  row.id = String(x);
  
  let cell4 = document.createElement('td');

  let deleteButton = document.createElement('button'); // Change var to let
  deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  deleteButton.type = "button";
  deleteButton.className = "deleteButton";

  deleteButton.onclick = function() {

    let rowID = deleteButton.closest("tr")?.id;
    
    console.log('rowID', rowID);
  }

  cell4.append(deleteButton);
  
  row.append(cell4);

  table.append(row);
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Such a saviour. Been debugging this for hours. Thanks